# Node.js - Checking for specific CharSet

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

currently I'm trying to create a new user in my mongodb database. The user also has to submit his email. 

My model looks like this:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    email: { 
        type: String, 
        required: true, 
        unique: true, 
        match: /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
}
```

This is just the important part of it because there I state, that mail has to match this specific charset. 

 Now my problem: If I update the email with the PATCH method

```
router.patch('/user', checkAuth, async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const id = req.body._id;

    const update = req.body;

    const options = { new: true };

    const result = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, options);

    if (!result) {
      throw createError(404, 'User does not exist');
    }

    res.send(result);

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);

    if (error instanceof mongoose.CastError) {
      return next(createError(400, 'Invalid User Id'));
    }

    next(error);
  }
})
```

The user can enter whatever he wants into the email field without it being checked for the charset. Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks in advance, Tom

Comment: Your question seems to be UI/front-end related, yet you provided backend code snippets.

Comment: Well thats what I thought too at first but the project manager said I should implement it into an API

Comment: [ValidatorJS](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-handle-data-validation-in-node-using-validatorjs/) could be of help to validate at an API-level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for pattern-matching in HTML, then you can validate your email address using this `<input>` tag:

```
<input pattern="/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/" required />
```

Check [ValidatorJS](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-handle-data-validation-in-node-using-validatorjs/) to validate at an API level.